# A question to the Wedderburn-Mal’cev decomposition

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, group-rings, decomposition-theorem

Excuse me,  I saw the result on the Wedderburn-Mal’cev decomposition of unital compact rings which M.I. Ursul and A. Tripe introduced in [the attached file](https://ibn.idsi.md/sites/default/files/imag_file/Totally%20bounded%20rings%20and%20their%20groups%20of%20units.pdf). However, I cannot contact them because emails are not found, and they may not exist. Could you please tell me where or sketch the proof of that theorem if you know? That result is as follows.

> **Theorem.** Let $R=S\oplus J(R)$ be Wedderburn-Mal'cev decomposition of a compact ring with identity of prime characteristic. Then $U(R)=U(S)\cdot(1+J(R))$, $U(S)\cap(1+J(R))=1$, i.e., $U(R)$ is a semidirect topological product of $U(S)$ and $1+J(R)$.

I also would like to ask more on the similar result of group algebras. Any counterexample, reference, or technique is very much appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: A compact ring is profinite so you should be able to get this from the finite case by passing to inverse limits

Comment: Excuse me, @BenjaminSteinberg, maybe I do not understand the things you say. Please sketch in detail. I am really grateful to you.

Comment: I can't really add too much detail because this is not my area but Kaplansky proved any compact ring $R$ is an inverese lmit of finite rings and the result is true for finite rings.  Since I believe that $U(R)$ and $J(R)$ are closed, this should follows from the finite case.  Note that a homomorphism of finite rings takes units onto units.

Comment: Oh, I just need such things. I understand the things you say and realize something. Thank you very much @BenjaminSteinberg.